# How to change a cursor to a pointer when hovering over a dynamic list using JQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, mouse-cursor

I have a list that I am appending to after the screen loads.  I want to change the cursor to a pointer after hovering.  So far I've tried using the .on event but it doesn't seem to be working.  Please look at the line with....   $('.item').on('mouseover', function() {
            $('.item').css('cursor', 'pointer');
        });

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').focus(function() {
        $('input[name=checklistInput]').css('outline-color','#FF0000');
    });
    $('#add').click(function() {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=checklistInput]').val();
        $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
        $('input[name=checklistInput]').val('');
    });

    $('.item').on('mouseover', function() {
        $('.item').css('cursor', 'pointer');    
    });

    $(document).on('click','.item', function() {
    $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Let me know if you need more details on what the overall goal of the code above is.

Thanks,

Comment: Problem in your code is you are not using delegation for mouseover event as you do for click event. BTW, you should use $(this) inside mouseover callback function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using plain css using `:hover` pseudo

```
.item:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

If you must use javascript, use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover` and reset to default on `mouseleave`.

Comment: Um yeah.  That was too easy.  I shouldn't have tried to force JQuery.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using plain css. Use of :Hover does not make any sense.

```
.item{

 cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just with css

```
.item:hover {cursor : pointer}
```